# Can Codeception Use both PHPBrowser is Some tests and WebDriver in others?

Tags: codeception

New Codeception user here, so apologies  in advance for what's like a super simple question. Is it possible to have a codeception project that runs some acceptance tests with the `PhpBrowser` driver, and others with the selenium `WebDriver` driver?

That is, I have an `acceptance.suite.yaml` that looks like this

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
   enabled:
      - WebDriver:
         url: 'http://localhost/'
         browser: firefox
         window_size: 1024x768
         wait: 10
         capabilities:
             unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

And a test that looks like this

```
#File: tests/acceptance/Science.php
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('see Science word in title ');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->seeInTitle('Science');
```

When I run

```
vendor/bin/codecept run
```

My tests run in selenium server.  (yay!)  However, there's other tests I'd like to run in the plain old `PhpBrowser`.  Is this possible without creating a second codeception suite?  If so, what does the configuration and/or test look like?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to use separate suites.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use WebDriver with PhantomJS browser as explained in Codeception documentation here http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver.

You need to download and run PhantomJS and then change the `browser` value from `firefox` to `phantomjs` in codeception configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate suite.